# android, creating/updating view from a method class running in an async task

Tags: android, android-layout

well i'm having some problem with android. Maybe its simple but i'm pretty new in android world (3, 4 days actually). Well i have an activity whitch runs an asyncTask that stands to reading data from a sensor network. The async Task only executes the function l.read() that by itself is a loop and keep allways "earing" the sensor network and when a new node joins to the sensor network, it tells the UI thread that one more node has joined, and so it has to update the view (witch has just one tab saying that no nodes exists and will now have to have one node available - besides this i even have to load an xml layout file for this tab ) the problem is that, when i preform the function that supostly creates a view and add a tab (that is properly working because when i call it on onCreate it works) the app do not respond anymore, however, Logcat gives me no errors. It look like it works but it is not showing anything.

Please, i dont expect you to read all this code, its just to hel to explain my problem. Its been 2 days and i'm still asking for a solution..

main Activity:

```
public class PrincipalActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener
{

private Button Send;
private Button Options;
private TextView ERROR;
private Bundle extras;
private String IP;
private String PORT;
private TabHost tabs;
private ligação l;
View m_vForm;
TabHost tabHost;
CustomView Cview;
ReadsData read;



//constructor
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    CustomView vv = new CustomView(PrincipalActivity.this,0);
    setContentView(vv);

    //instanciating the objects
    IP = new String();
    PORT = new String();      
    extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    IP = extras.getString("IP");  //get the IP and port from the previous activity
    PORT = extras.getString("PORT");
    ERROR = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ERROR);   
    tabs = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    tabs.setup();
    Send = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SendCommand);
    Send.setOnClickListener(this);
    Options = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Options);
    Options.setOnClickListener(this);
  //=========================

    CreateAView("No Nodes",false);
    l = new ligação(IP, Integer.parseInt(PORT),this);  //CLASS LIGAÇÃO
   // RunnableThread rT1 = new RunnableThread("t1",l,this);

    read = new ReadsData();
    read.execute();

    //Textviews (Values)


}

public void AddUpdateNodes(Nodes n,int func)
{
    //func is 0 if it it to add a node or 1 if it is to update an existing one
    if(func == 0)
    {
        String s = new String();
        s+= n.GETSourceNodeID();
        CreateAView(s, true);
        Cview.addNewNode(n);        
    }
    if(func == 1)
        Cview.UpdateNodeInformation(n);
}


public void onClick(View v) 
{

    if(v == Send)
    {
        // if i call CreateAView here it works ok
        ERROR.setText(IP);

    }

    if(v == Options)
    {

        ERROR.setText(PORT);
    }
}

    // CREATING A VIEW WITH THE TABS
public void CreateAView(String s,boolean nodesAvailable)
{

     m_vForm = createTABForm(s,nodesAvailable);
     setContentView(m_vForm);
}

 private ViewGroup createTABForm(String s,boolean nodesAvailable1)
 {
    final boolean nodesAvailable = nodesAvailable1;

        // construct the TAB Host
        tabHost = new TabHost(this);
        tabHost.setLayoutParams(  new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)  );

        // the tabhost needs a tabwidget, that is a container for the visible tabs
        TabWidget tabWidget = new TabWidget(this);
        tabWidget.setId(android.R.id.tabs);
        tabWidget.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

        tabHost.addView(tabWidget, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(      LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)   ); 

        // the tabhost needs a frame layout for the views associated with each visible tab
        FrameLayout frameLayout = new FrameLayout(this);
        frameLayout.setId(android.R.id.tabcontent);
        frameLayout.setPadding(0, 65, 0, 0);
        tabHost.addView(frameLayout, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(   LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)   ); 

        // setup must be called if you are not initialising the tabhost from XML
        tabHost.setup(); 

        // create the tabs
        TabSpec ts = tabHost.newTabSpec("TAB_TAG_2");
        ts.setIndicator(s); // creating a tabb with the specified name
        ts.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory(){
             public View createTabContent(String tag)
             {
                 // -- this tab contains a single control - the listview -- //
                 Cview = new CustomView(PrincipalActivity.this,nodesAvailable);
                 return Cview;   // IS AN OBJECT FROM THE CLASS CustomView
             }
        });

        tabHost.addTab(ts); 
        return tabHost;
    } 




 ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
 //Async Tasks
 private class ReadsData extends AsyncTask 
 {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {
        l.read();
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute()
     {
        l.SocketClosed_();
     }
 }

}
```

---

```
    //CLASS CUSTOM VIEW

 public CustomView(Context context,boolean NodesAvailable)
 {
   super(context);

   if(NodesAvailable) //loads a layout
   {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

       View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.finallayout,this);

       //only after inflate
        ADC0 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ADC00);

   }
   else  // loads another layout
   {
       LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
       View view=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.no_nodes,this);
   }

 }



 public void addNewNode(Nodes n)
 {
     String s = new String();


     s = new String();
     s += n.GETSensores(0).GETvalor();
     ADC0.setText(s);


 }

 public void UpdateNodeInformation(Nodes n)
 {
     String s = new String();
     s += n.GETSourceNodeID();

     //if(s.equals())

 }

}
```

---

```
    //SOME CODE OF LIGAÇÃO CLASS
  public class ligação 
  {
      protected PrincipalActivity cont;
    //Constructors
    public ligação(String ss,int Port,PrincipalActivity c){ s=ss; p=Port;cont = c; }

       public void read() 
   {
           while(flag)
           {
              ...
              cont.AddUpdateNodes(node, 0);
              ...
           }
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's weird that your app doesn't crash , since all UI operations should be done on the UI thread . maybe it's because the asynctask's thread has crashed but not the ui thread , and that's why nothing occurs.
anyway , in order to create/update the view within the asyncTask , you can use any of the following , which will post something to the UI thread to do as soon as it can :

1. use a handler.
2. use [publishProgress](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#publishProgress%28Progress...%29).
3. use [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29).

Comment: Well, i have talk with a friend of me and he said that i could be possibly updating another context and so, it does not appear nothing on the screen. He told me to see intents and that it might solve my problem. What do you think of this?

Comment: not sure if i understand . if what you do is constantly sending intents , it might reduce the performance since intents are usually sent over the system (so that any app could handle them) . is that what you mean? if so , why not putting the logic exactly on the same activity that shows the textView?

Comment: you might also be able to put the logic right inside the custom view of the clock . just remember to stop the asyncTask when needed (maybe automatically via the onDetachedFromWindow method.

Comment: so You are suggesting to put the code int the Async Task in the activity? I've already remembered that but i thought that it would be a bad idea because it will mix view with backgroud service

Comment: but the view will only be updated when the time is changing , and nobody else needs to be notified about the time , no? so why not? even as a custom view , i think it's possible , since it's not the first time that such a thing exist (probably the clock widgets on other OSs work this way) . also , why do you call it a background service?

Comment: i'm calling a backgroud service because i need to be listening on the sensor network information and get all this.. when a new sensor is on the net i have to create another view with another tab.. else, i just have to update it

Comment: what is the information of the sensor that is relevant to the showing of the current time ? anyway , try to use intents only for starting to listen and for stopping to listen . for updates , there is no need for so many intents being sent .

Comment: well i think the problem is that somehow i'm not acceeding to the ui thread, and so it creates a view but when i do setcontent view, all 
becomes the same way it was except that no no buttons respond.  when i update a node information i mean that i need to update temperature values etc and show ir on the ADC0.. ADC7 TextViews.. :-/ but.. as i said i think it isnt reaching the ui thread otherwise or the app stops or it works.. Ps i'm getting you suggestion and i'm putting all in the asyncTask.. One thing.. are anything that prevents me to do set contentview(new view()) after the method oncreate

Comment: and one more thing.. the loop that i have in the async task (to listen the sensor network) only runs one time.. Oh god

Comment: i think it's better to use a handler instead of an asynctask , but it depends on the project . asynctask should be a relatively short task , which you don't mind when it will occur , and that you can only assume that at least one asyncTask will run at the same time .

Comment: Hello, i've already resolved my problem. I just moved some code to another class that extends Async task and did some more changes it is now running ok.. So you are saying that i should use handlers instead of AsyncTask? As far as i read Async Tasks uses handlers and callbacks but encapsulated..

Comment: but asynctask also uses extra threads while for handlers you just post a runnable to be executed on the UI thread at the time that you wish for it to occur . because you need to update the UI , it's just a perfect candidate . what do you do on the asynctask ? just sleep? if so , that's a waste of a thread since it's really not needed. in short , only you can decide what is best for your app , since you are the only one that knows what should occur on your app.

Comment: do anybody knows (besides this has not to do with the matter of the thread) how can i compare current tab with another tab? Like            if(tabhost.getCurrenttabtag().equals(    tabhost.gettabtag()  ))

Comment: please put this new question in a new post , as it's really not related to the current question .

Comment: also please tick this answer with "V" if it helped you .  :)